# How to develop in Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I need to develop around $\pi$ $f(x)=sin(\frac{x}{2})$, and to determinate the convergence interval and the radius of convergence of the serie.

I've started by finding all the derivate

$$f(x) = sin(\frac{x}{2})$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{cos(\frac{x}{2})}{2}$$
$$f''(x) = \frac{-sin(\frac{x}{2})}{4}$$
$$f'''(x) = \frac{-cos(\frac{x}{2})}{8}$$
$$f''''(x) = \frac{sin(\frac{x}{2})}{16}$$

Then I evaluated each of them for $x = \pi$
$$f(\pi) = 1$$
$$f'(\pi) = 0$$
$$f''(\pi) = -\frac{1}{4}$$
$$f'''(\pi) = 0$$
$$f''''(\pi) = \frac{1}{16}$$

Now using the taylor expension formula, I've came to

$$\sin(\frac{x}{2}) = 1 + 0 - \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{2!}(x-\pi) + 0 + \frac{\frac{1}{16}}{4!}(x-\pi) + ... + \frac{f(n-1)(a)}{(n-1)}(x-a)$$

Now this is where I'm stuck. Maybe I've done something wrong so this is why I'm stuck ? Else, what am I missing ?

Please don't just throw the solution without explanation as this is homework and I need to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the $n$th derivative of $\sin(x/2)$ (it is not hard to prove) which is given by

$$ f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{1}{2^n}\sin\left( \frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi n}{2} \right).$$

Using the above formula for the $n$th derivative to constrct the Taylor series at the point $x=\pi$ as

$$ \sin(x/2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(\pi)}{n!}(x-\pi)^n. $$

You can simplify $f^{(n)}(\pi)$ as $ f^{(n)}(\pi) = \frac{(-1)^{n/2}}{2^n} $ if $n$ is even and $f^{(n)}(\pi) =0$ if $n$ is odd.